# Browser close confirmation for tablets

Tags: javascript

There are questions regarding "Show confirmation before closing browser".

I am using this one:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;

// For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
}

// For Safari
return 'Sure?';
```

};

This works okay; **but** the problem is it's not working for tablets. I need a solution which works on tablets as well please.

So if I refresh my browser on tablets it also works, but if I close my browser (click on browser cross symbol) it's not working on tablets.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's not guaranteed at all that browsers will honour this behaviour in any way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#prompt-to-unload-a-document. You may simply be out of luck.

Comment: thanks for hint , Confusion is that in pc , or in table , browser is Same (i.e chrome), But it works in PC, but not in tablet

Comment: Or may be if there is any way to do this other than "onbeforeunload"

Comment: Google may have decided that an onbeforeunload popup is disruptive in terms of UX on a mobile device; e.g. how do you deal with incoming phone calls which may take over at any second and may effectively close the browser window (throw it out of memory so whatever information you entered is gone when you return)…

Comment: Just because the browsers are marketed with the same name ("Chrome") does not mean they use the exact same code. For instance, Chrome on iPad uses the same rendering engine as Safari because Apple does not allow competition in rendering engines on the iPad.